# Replacing "D-minor" and "G-Major" with "F-major" and "G 7 no 5" (in a 2-5-1 chord progression)?

Tags: theory, piano, chords, chord-progressions

This ["warm-up" video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKMNIB9sk18&t=35s) first goes over what it calls as "bookkeeping" (from 21-to-35).

They establish that the "warm-up" will take place in c-major and will follow the chord progression:
2-5-1

So first she begins by playing the D-minor, G-major, then C-major.

Then she says that she's "minding the voice leading", and switches to playing a set of new chords that are not actually inversions of the previously played chords. (I had to look up what chords she plays) It appears as though she's playing: F Major, "G 7 no 5", and then C-major.

It sounds quite nice and similar to the previous progression, but I have no idea how someone comes up with that, or how this is still a "2-5-1" progression.

Any intution or understanding here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

The necessary observation is that her left hand is always playing the roots of the `ii-V-I` progression: `D-G-C`.

---

Going step by step through her modifications:

1. `ii-V-I` in root position (`Dmin - Gmaj - Cmaj`)

"Ok let's mind the voice-leading"

2. Looking only at her right hand, she appears to play `Fmaj - G7(omit 5) - Cmaj`. However, you have to consider her left hand. In actuality, she's playing `Dmin7 - G7 - Cmaj`. It's okay to omit the 5 in a seventh chord, because that pitch contributes relatively little to the overall sound of the chord.

"Better"

3. Now she plays `Dmin9 - G7add13 - Cmaj9` omitting the 5 of all three chords. Again, she's using standard piano voicings for those chords.

"Still missing something..."

4. Here she just adds pedal and a gentler touch to the chords.

"Better" #2

5. Finally, she re-voices the chords again and plays `Dmin7(include 5) - G7(omit 5) - Cmaj7`. Again, if one considers only her right hand, then she's playing `F/C - G7(omit 5) - Emin/B`. But one has to include all tones, including the left hand, to interpret chords, so in fact she's playing an ordinary jazz ii-V-I progression.

"Yes..."